# Installing a tar.bz2

Tags: installation, install-from-source, tar

I am trying to install laidout-0.0o91.tar.bz2. its a publishing program for Linux. can you please give me the right terminal instructions to install this on my system.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the folder you downloaded the laidout-0.0o91.tar.bz2 from the terminal and type,

```
tar -jxvf laidout-0.0o91.tar.bz2
```

then type,

```
cd laidout-0.0o91
```

afterwards,

```
less README
```

you will see the installation instructions in your terminal window.

(by the way, if your processor is 64bit, there's a .deb installer to download. Just download that and then double click it to install.)

Comment: i think i downloaded it to an archive file.

Comment: well, if you downloaded the laidout-0.0o91.tar.bz2 Downloads folder, you have to type " cd ~/Downloads/ " in terminal and then continue typing the commands listed in the answer. Can you tell me which folder is laidout-0.0o91.tar.bz2 currently at?

Answer (score 4):

If you have the 64bit version of ubuntu installed, there is a one-click-installer (.deb) for that version located at [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/laidout/files/laidout/0.091/laidout_0.091_amd64.deb/download). All you need to do for that is download and double click the "laidout_0.091_amd64.deb" file.

(If you're not sure if you have 64 bit Linux installed, open a terminal and type "arch". If you see "x86_64" you have 64 bit and can use the .deb package listed above.)

If you have 32bit Ubuntu, you have two options. The simple solution is to download the 32bit package, but it is only for version 0.09. If there is **not** a specific reason why you need 0.091, then download the one-click-installer package [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/laidout/files/laidout/0.09/laidout_0.09_i386.deb/download) and run it just like I mentioned earlier (click the .deb file in your Downloads folder, and click "install" when prompted)

If there **is** a specific reason why you absolutely need that version **AND** you are using 32 bit ubuntu, than here is the second option, which involves building the package from source. The general directions are as follows, but may not work depending on the package.

**Prepare  your system to build from source**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

**Install from the .tar.bz2 you downloaded**

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -jxvf laidout-0.0o91.tar.bz2
cd laidout-0.0o91
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

If it complains at any step about missing packages, install them with

```
sudo apt-get install <name-of-missing-package>
```

Again, only follow these steps if you have 32 bit Ubuntu **and** you cannot use version 0.09 instead of 0.091.

Best of Luck!